# how can i send a array in json i have used json.stringify

Tags: json, react-native

How can i send this array in json format it going as {'test_ids[]' : '[value]'}
i want it as {'test_ids[]' : 'value'} can anyone help me with this please

```
  const [multitest, setTests] = React.useState([]);
.post(url,
     
     {'test_ids[]': JSON.stringify(multitest)},
     {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
```

Comment: Can't we just `pop` the `value` out of the array? `'test_ids[]': multitest.pop()}`

Comment: it goes one by one i want to send it in one go after selecting the test just continue

Answer (score 0):

If the array - `multitest` - has only one element, then simply extract it as such

```
JSON.stringify(multitest[0]);
```

Comment: but there will be multiple test only one item wont go

Comment: So basically you want the result of `JSON.stringify(multitest)` to look like this? - `['val1', 'val2', 'val3']`

Comment: Are you trying to apply `JSON.stringify()` to each element in the array seperately?

Comment: no actually i want to send this in json like   {'test_ids[]' : 'val1' ,'test_ids[]' : 'val2' , 'test_ids[]' : 'val3'}

Comment: if 'test_ids[]' is going to act as a key this can cause problems since all keys are same. You should use something like this instead: {`'test_ids_1' : 'val1' ,'test_ids_2' : 'val2' , 'test_ids_3' : 'val3'}`. This can be achieved by iterating through the array and assigning the key created using the iteration index via concatenation and adding them to an object `obj`. And then simply take the object and use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to get the result

Comment: but its in array so i want to send the array using json ,,,because formdata is not working